# Preserve Color with Gaussian Blurring and Sobel Operators

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to utilize a gaussian blur on an image as a preprocessing step to using a sobel edge detection filter.

I have previously implemented sobel and gaussian blurring operators on a greyscale image effectively, however, I have never attempted to use them on color images.

Previously, I have just been taking the red component of my pixel data as the RGB are all the same in greyscale.

Do I need to first convert my RGB images to greyscale?

If not, how can I use all 3 color channels with the kernels for each operator?

Comment: What would you hope to achieve with doing it on all three channels? The Sobel operator is a derivative operator, so it tells you the *change* in color values between neighboring pixels. Do you actually need to know the change in red, green, or blue values specifically? If not, just convert to grayscale. What do you mean by "preserve color"? You could for e.g. create an edge image from grayscale which functions as a mask, and then mask your original image with the edge image which will show the original colors of the image at the edge points.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply linear filters to each color channel independently. Gaussian blur and the Sobel operator are linear filters. Typically one would separate the three channels as three grey-value images, and filter them separately, then compose the three results into a new RGB image. But if your software allows applying a convolution on a multi-channel image, you won't need to do this process manually.

Do note that applying Gaussian blur and then the Sobel operator to determine the gradient is sub-optimal. You are better off directly computing the gradient using Gaussian derivatives. [Here is an old blog post of mine that describes Gaussian derivatives](http://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/22). In short, applying a convolution with the derivative of a Gaussian (which you can determine analytically and sample) yields the exact derivative of the smoothed image. Note that the Gaussian is separable (and so is its derivative), meaning that the 2D convolution can be applied as two 1D convolutions, saving lots of computations.